# Select all rows where table1.column1 = table2.column1 where at least one value table2.column2 = 1

Tags: mysql-5.5

I have two tables in a MySQL database

table1:
column1 column2

table2:
column1 column2

I want to select all rows where table1.column1 = table2.column1 if at least one row table2.column2 = 1

```
table1
12   test1
13   test3


table2
12   1
12   0
12   0
12   0
12   0
13   0
13   0
13   0
13   0

Result should be
12   1  test1
12   0  test1
12   0  test1
12   0  test1
12   0  test1
```

I've tried different JOIN statements but I either get all values from table2 or a single value

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INNER JOIN` with `EXISTS`:

```
select t2.column1,
       t2.column2,
       t1.column2
from table2 t2
left join table1 t1 on t2.column1=t1.column1
where exists ( select 1 
               from table2 tbl2 
               where tbl2.column1=t2.column1 
               and tbl2.column2=1
              );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=411bba6838857d30d9776e2c5c23b8dc

The exist part will select all the the values on column1 on table2  where at least one value on column2 is equal to 1.